# Importing symbols from external libraries into the context of an Eclipse PyDev project

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm working on some Python projects in Eclipse (via PyDev).

In a NetBeans PHP project, I can add symbols from an external library to the autocomplete and "open symbol" commands by adding the path to the project's "Include Path" object:

[image: Location of "Include Path" in a NetBeans PHP project]

For example, by adding the PHPUnit source to the project's include path, PHPUnit classes will appear in my autocomplete, I can command-click on PHPUnit class names to go to their declarations, etc.

Is there a similar feature in Eclipse/PyDev?  How do I make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the project properties, there is a `PyDev - PYTHONPATH` option that will allow you to specify External Libraries.

The folders added to the External Libraries **have to contain Python modules**.

In other words, if you add a folder that contains `__init__.py`, you need to go up one more directory.